# How to get the bigger icon

Tags: winapi, shell

I CAN get the associated icon just fine, and draw it accordingly,
however, I want to extract the FULL Icon information not just the
32x32 (or the 16x16) pixels that the SHGetFileInfo allows.

For instance, I might want to display the 128x128 icon (or even
256x256) that is stored in the icon file inside the executable. And I
can only accomplish this with the full file name.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(VS.85).aspx, LoadImage() uses cxDesired and cyDesired parameters to choose the dimensions when loading an icon.